# javascript halt on errors

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have a hard-to-locate bug affecting a JS code-base; periodically, an array is accessed out-of-bounds, which causes a `TypeError: initial[data[(i + offset)]] is undefined` error (note: similar indexing is found in dozens of places). Is there any way to make errors fatal and stop execution at that point so that the stack trace can be examined?

How can I force these warnings to become errors without adding throws() or if-statements all around the code-base? Is there any way to force a "strict" operation, something like the `-Wall -Wfatal-errors` flags found in gcc?

I am using the latest stable FireBug+Firefox, but could transition to the Chrome console if there are any mechanisms there.

Comment: I would expect the line number of error shown in the console.

Comment: I can locate the errors easily enough; the problem is that they are not caused at that point, but higher up the stack. I can trace each of them individually, by placing a conditional breakpoint -- but I wonder if there is any way to trap *all* warnings in this way, instead of one-by-one.

Comment: So, to clarify: this is not "how do I debug this", but rather "how can I debug it more efficiently"

Comment: With internet explorer (probably FF and Chrome have similar config), you can configure the browser to popup when an error occurs. From this point, you have the opportunity to attach a registered debugger.

Comment: I would be surprised if the call stack is not available even when you place a breakpoint.

Comment: @AlvinWong my goal is to avoid having to place these breakpoints; if there is any warning, I would like script execution to halt and let me look at the stack *without having to manually add breakpoints*. (The breakpoints would have to be conditional, and setting them is so vexing that I ended up looking for a better way)

Comment: @SteveB how do I configure that with Firefox/Firebug? Not going to use IE under Linux...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enable [break on…](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel#Breakpoints) [all errors](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Break_On_All_Errors).

Chrome Devtools and Opera Dragonfly provide similar options.

Comment: Does not seem to be available in the Firebug 1.11.1 - the setting is not where the manual says it should be; it is available through about:config as `extensions.firebug.breakOnErrors`, but appears to have no effect

Comment: But you threw me on the right track: console > Show Stack-trace with Errors solves the problem nicely. If you care to edit your answer, I'll accept it.